# Diophantine equation not solvable in $\mathbb{Q}$, but in $\mathcal{O}_p$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, p-adic-number-theory

I'm trying to think of an example of a diophantine equation which can be solved in $ \mathcal{O}_p$ (meaning it can be solved $\mod p^k$ for all $ k $) for all prime $ p $'s, but not in $\mathbb{Q}$

I don't really think that's such an easy task - and probably there is some classic answer, but I can't think of one.

I would appreciate some help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this paper is mentioned $3x^3+4y^3+5z^3=0$, referred to there as 'Selmer's example'
http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/selmerexample.pdf

Answer (score 4):

Here's one I read a number of years ago
that works mod $p$ for every prime $p$.
I don't know if it works for $\mathcal{O}_p$.

Let
$f(x)
=(x^2-2)(x^2-3)(x^2-6)
$.

$f$ obviously has no rational roots.

If
$x^2-2$ and $x^2-3$
have no roots mod $p$,
then 2 and 3 are not
quadratic residues mod $p$,
so 6 *is* a quadratic residue mod $p$,
so $x^2-6$ has a root.

Comment: For primes $p\not=2, 3,$ it follows from Hensel's lemma that there are solutions in $\mathbb Z_p.$ Also apparently there are no solutions modulo $4.$ For $p=3,$ there is no $x$ with $x^2\equiv2\pmod3,$ so a solution $x$ must satisfy $3\mid x.$ Suppose $3^n\mid\mid x,$ then $3^{4n+1}\not\mid f(x),$ thus there is no solution in $\mathbb Z_3.$

Comment: I think the problem here is that 2 is not a square mod 3. You can improve it - I believe the equation $(x^2 -2) (x^2 - 17)(x^2 - 2\cdot 17) = 0$ has solutions mod $ p^k $ for all $ p $ and $ k $